# geo spatial application: mySql vs CouchDB vs others

Tags: mysql, node.js, geolocation, couchdb, geospatial

I am developing an application on google map and checking out various options to store and retrieve spatial information within a bounding box.

Initially I thought MySql was not a good option, but after checking http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html and http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html, looks like I can use MySql and it does support my use cases.

I was also evaluating node.js and couchdb with geocouch.. With modules like socket.io, geo etc looks like this is also a good choice. check out the book "Getting Started with GEO, CouchDB, and Node.js". My application would be 1 page application and I do not foresee if I would require rdbms anytime in future.

i have also seen this - http://nodeguide.com/convincing_the_boss.html and this makes me little apprehensive about whether to go with node.js-geocouch....

> If the architecture for your next apps reads like the cookbook of
>   NoSQL ingredients, please pause for a second and read this.
>
> Yes, Redis, CouchDB, MongoDB, Riak, Casandra, etc. all look really
>   tempting, but so did that red apple Eve couldn't resist. If you're
>   already taking a technological risk with using node.js, you shouldn't
>   multiply it with more technology you probably don't fully understand
>   yet.
>
> Sure, there are legitimate use cases for choosing a document oriented
>   database. But if you are trying to build a business on top of your
>   software, sticking to conservative database technology (like postgres
>   or mysql) might just outweigh the benefits of satisfying your inner
>   nerd and impressing your friends.

What is your opinion ?

Comment: +1. MySQL spatial facilities were underpowered until 5.6.1 when proper spatial queries [were added](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries) that use the object geometries rather than just the minimum bounding rectangle. It would be interesting to get an answer from someone that's used them (I haven't yet)

Comment: You might also want to check out PostGIS: http://postgis.refractions.net/.

Comment: Finally I am using mongodb and it's working like a charm so far in node.js.. I am able to do a radius search... So far I am storing all basic data types (String, Number etc)... I do not know how would I store a file/binary/blob... I have to see this when requirement arises..

Comment: I am interested in this as well. Can you elaborate on your MongoDB solution, perhaps as an answer to your own question?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GeoCouch sounds like a good solution in your case. If you want to have an easy installation, you can have a look at [Couchbase Single Server](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-single/current), which is basically a CouchDB with GeoCouch included (check out the [Developer Preview for 2.0](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-single/2.0).

Comment: Just wanted to make clear that Couchbase is not the same as CouchDB. For example the APIs are different, as there is almost no REST interface in Couchbase: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-introduction-migration-couchdb.html